# Asker thinks there's a bug in their code but there isn't, should you answer explaining why not?

Tags: discussion, answers

Yesterday I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193577/impossible-to-find-bug-in-a-program-that-equalizes-wealth-in-a-group-uva-10137), where the asker asks for help debugging an "impossible to find" bug in their code. It's a well-formed question: has MCVE, expected/actual output and brief description of the problem. However, I'm convinced (as are several other commenters) that there isn't actually a bug and it's a problem with the test case.

In such a case, is it a good idea to answer the question by doing a worked example of the test case and showing that the actual output is correct? On the one hand, it could be little more than a typo in the test case or bug in the reference answer (in this specific case it's an online coding competition), but on the other hand "the problem is in the test not the code" is something you encounter from time to time while programming, so why shouldn't it be on topic?

Comment: If the code they've provided does not in fact reproduce their problem then they have *not* provided an MCVE.  If they have provided an MCVE, then they, by definition, have provided code that reproduces their problem.

Comment: @Servy that depends what the "problem" is. If it's a logic problem with their code, they haven't provided code that reproduces it, because it doesn't exist. If the problem is that actual output doesn't match the expected, then they *have* provided that. It's just that the issue is with the expected output. The way you are defining it makes it impossible for the OP to know in advance if they have provided an adequate MCVE without knowing the answer to their own question (in which case they wouldn't ask it).

Comment: Well, happens all the time, worst bug is the one that isn't there and invariably gets somebody to ask for help.  The usual issue is that the OP has not provided enough evidence to work out the other explanation and all you got is a theory.  You'll have to post a comment and ask for more.  Once you have enough, or do now, then, sure, let it rip.

Comment: I flagged this question as too broad. I think this is a case by case problem. If you can help the OP and you can't reproduce the bug then just comment or answer that. It also depends on how common the bug is, eg. if it's in the standard config provided in common IDE's, eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999661/stringbuilder-tostring-is-printed-as-empty-string-in-eclipse-console-when-too , point out errors in the question that can be corrected and if all else fails, think about the usefulness of the question for future readers.

Answer (score 13):

If the code the OP provided can be executed as is and does not in any way produce anything that can be described as a problem, then there is no valid question. That seems to be the case here.

If the OP provides the code *and the test case* and you can clearly see why the test case fails (even if that's just an issue with the test case), then there is a question there. But lacking a test case, and seeing just code that works, there's nothing to answer.

→ Close as *Problem can no longer be reproduced*, *Why isn't this code working* or *Unclear what you're asking*, depending on what fits best.

Comment: What if its actually an environment problem? Then they have provided code that reproduces it... but just for them.

Comment: If they can detail the environment and you can reproduce it in that same environment, fine. The question is always: *is it reproducible?* If yes, fine. If not, well… *no longer reproducible.*

Comment: You seem to be implying the question lacks a test case. The question does include the failing test case.

Answer (score 6):

I find this situation to be borderline.

In the past I have occasionally written an answer that basically says "your code is fine; you have X, Y, Z setting wrong in your compiler" or "actually, your code is fine; this is a compiler bug and you should raise it with GCC".

Meanwhile, strictly speaking, we are not answering the actual question posed ("what is wrong with my code") and the strictly correct thing to do would be to leave that information in a comment and close as "can no longer be reproduced".

You have to use your judgement as to which is best in the moment; I *think* my heuristic involves some guesswork on how many other people may encounter the exact same problem, even if the problem isn't quite what the OP thought it was.

Comment: Optimization settings can be the _root_ of all frustration similar to this. And, even with all compiler flags provided, differences in optimization between versions of the compiler can be sneaky. I agree that there's no blanket answer for this. And don't forget those doozies that boil down to a synchronization issue, you can spend the better part of an afternoon reproducing that.

Comment: @TimPost: Indeed.

Answer (score 4):

I've spent the better part of some afternoons trying to reproduce thread synchronization problems that I thought could exist *in theory* and never managed to do it, but I very firmly believed that *something* about the OP's setup wasn't present in my tests and that they had a valid question.

One case turned out to be because the OP was running an unstable kernel.

[This answer by Lightness Races In Orbit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343714/50049) is the best advice, there's no blanket way in which to treat these. And it can be a fun exercise to think *okay, what about their setup is different from mine and probably never occurred to them to mention?*

So, while some of these do turn out to just be wild goose chases, putting the question on hold kind of removes a lot of motivation for others to spend a little time thinking about what could be going on. So, please don't put them on hold if you think there's even a *small* chance that there's something weird at play.

And it's fine if the answer is "It's the test, not the code" up to and including suggesting that folks run unit and integration tests on stable operating systems :) If there's nothing otherwise wrong with the question, perhaps just make a note to revisit it in a few days and see if something marvelous or downright funny was to blame.

Now if the OP goes back and edits "Duh, didn't realize [thing]" - then it's something that doesn't need to be open for answers.